# Display with smarty in same div products with same value

Tags: php, smarty

I have 4 products, and 2 of them with the same `order_id`.

Here is my smarty output `$orders`:

```
Array (8) 
0 => Array (11) 
  id => "85" 
  order_id => "1" 
  user_email => "jeff@gmail.com" 
  total_price => "2000" 
  status => "Pending payment" 
  order_option_id => "1" 
  image => "Luxury-Sofa-for-Main-Room-at-Home-Design-Luxury-with-Stunning-Outdoor.jpg" 
  title => "ruyrytur" 
  variants => "" 
  quantity => "1" 
  unit_price => "123.00" 
1 => Array (11) 
  id => "98" 
  order_id => "2" 
  user_email => "jeff@gmail.com" 
  total_price => "20000" 
  status => "Pending payment" 
  order_option_id => "2" 
  image => "Modern-Green-Home-Architecture-house-plans.jpg" 
  title => "Vewlix 1080p (black and white)" 
  variants => "Panel 2 players (+50 euros) Red backlight (+100 euros) Screen 1440p (+400 eur..." 
  quantity => "3" 
  unit_price => "2680.00" 
2 => Array (11) 
  id => "99" 
  order_id => "2" 
  user_email => "jeff@gmail.com" 
  total_price => "20000" 
  status => "Pending payment" 
  order_option_id => "2" 
  image => "amazing-modern-villa-Freshome-02.jpg" 
  title => "Vewlix 1080p (red and white)" 
  variants => "Panel 2 players (+50 euros)" 
  quantity => "1" 
  unit_price => "2000.00" 
3 => Array (11) 
  id => "102" 
  order_id => "4" 
  user_email => "jeff@gmail.com" 
  total_price => "2000" 
  status => "1" 
  order_option_id => "4" 
  image => "amazing-modern-villa-Freshome-02.jpg" 
  title => "Vewlix 1080p (red and white)" 
  variants => "Panel 2 players (+50 euros)" 
  quantity => "1" 
  unit_price => "2000.00"
```

I tried many foreach to "merge" the products with the same order_id in the same div without success

This is the output I'd like:

```
<div> 
  id 85 
</div> 
<div> 
  id 98 
  id 99 
</div> 
<div> 
  id 102 
</div>
```

My foreach (that simply loop into results)

```
            {foreach $orders as $orderdisplay}

                    <table class="table" style="border: 1px solid black;">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td>ITEM</td>
                                <td>QUANTITY</td>
                                <td>PRICE</td>
                                <td>STATUS</td>
                            </tr> 
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                </td>
                                <td>{$orderdisplay.title}<br />{$orderdisplay.variants}</td>
                                <td>{$orderdisplay.quantity}</td>
                                <td>{$orderdisplay.total_price}</td>
                                <td>{$orderdisplay.status}</td>
                            </tr>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <span>{$orderdisplay.total_price}</span>
            {/foreach}
```

Comment: where is this said foreach loop that you did, you'll need to post the codes too

Comment: Question edited. I forgot to post my actual foreach.

Comment: if you want same products to be in the same group, you need to reconstruct the initial array, you'll need to tweak the smarty loop but that's the general idea

Comment: its the usual `foreach($original_orders as $value) { $grouped_orders[$value['order_id']][] = $value; }`

Comment: I found the way to do it:             `{foreach $orders as $n} 
               {$OID[{$n.order_id}][] = $n} 
            {/foreach} 

            {foreach $OID as $o_id => $orders4OrderID} 
            <div style="background: grey; margin-bottom: 10px;"> 
               {foreach $orders4OrderID as $order} 
                  product id {$order.id} 
               {/foreach} 
            </div> 
            {/foreach}`
thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Solution given on the smarty forum by bsmither:

```
{foreach $orders as $n} 
    {$OID[{$n.order_id}][] = $n} 
{/foreach} 

{foreach $OID as $o_id => $orders4OrderID} 
   <div> 
      {foreach $orders4OrderID as $order} 
         product id {$order.id} 
      {/foreach} 
   </div> 
{/foreach}
```